Making first-order logic perspectival
How do linguists and computer scientists typically make propositions in first-order logic "perspectival", in the way that natural language gives us pronouns like "I", relative times like "in the past", and demonstratives like "this"?

Edited the language to make the premise fact-based to discourage more down-voting. Feel free to rollback.

You ask:

How do we make propositions in first-order logic "perspectival", in the way that natural language gives us pronouns like "I", relative times like "in the past", and demonstratives like "this"?

So, the response is complicated and idiosyncratic, but the simplest answer is that you can use FOL with pronouns just like any other topic. It's done in AI research all of the time. Languages like prolog and Haskell and custom grammars allow you to implement logic in a customized fashion. FOL as a system places no restrictions on what you can name variables, a fact that many AI researches have taken advantage of since the Dartmouth. For instance, there's nothing wrong with the formalism:

Is(snow,white), Ist(Schnee,weiß) or even Am(I,happy) or Happy(I)

Remember, predicates are typically defined by comprehensions. Thus, we can define Happy(I) with set-builder notation. It's not exotic to say ∃!x∀P : { x is Julius Hamilton of Copenhagen in the set of all persons P on earth. }. It's not something you'll find in mathematical literature, but that's because mathematicians stick to the discourse of mathematical logic, not because it violates how an FOL or formal system can be constructed. There are academics who do move in that direction, however: linguists and computer scientists.
Discourse representation theory is a set of approaches to modeling broader texts of language that go beyond mere mathematical propositions. In NLP and linguistics research, for instance consider HPSG where the intent is to model, not a mathematical conjecture, but the full length and breadth of human discourse; there are more complicated formal systems that handle endophora, deixis, pragmatics, and other linguistic features that mathematicians and logicians often don't care about. (Implicit in this claim is that mathematicians and logicians don't have a superior claim to expertise in the use of formal semantics over linguists and computer scientists.)
This approach, which hasn't been as widely received as the initial work of Frege, Russell, Tarski, and others, is popular in some academic communities and started with the work of Richard Montague and what is now known as Montague Semantics (SEP). Barbara Partee and other linguists under the banner of linguistic formal semantics have advanced the programme over the years, and today there are a number of NL-centric grammars that go far above and beyond the formalisms typically studied by logicians. A contemporary example of a standard that embraces pronouns and appositives by combining the legacy of transformational and generative grammatical paradigms from the 1960's is dynamic semantics (SEP).
Besides using a broader array of constructs in NL syntax, discourse often takes into account such features as logical possible worlds, textual contexts, and propositional presuppositions. For instance, consider this example from the article which uses a pronoun. From the SEP:

"(1) Mary met a student yesterday. He needed help." [is represented by] "(3)  ∃x(student(x)∧met(m,x)∧need-help(x))"

Here, the pronoun is encoded indirectly as a variable invoked as student(x) and "He needed help" represents the "he" with the x which is then conjoined with other predicates effacing the pronoun and relying on the variable x to bind together the person by the pronouns.
My recommendation to you if you're looking for a ready-made system is to study type-theoretical grammar (GB) which is based on Martin-Löf's ITT and is in the same vein as Montague's original grammar. Also, the best book I've found so far on formal semantics is Ronnie Cann's Formal Semantics: An Introduction (GB). While Ranta and his work only have a few references in the SEP, you have the advantage that the author is still an active researcher in Gothenburg not far from you and that he has lead efforts to build a programming language with a custom, effectively context-sensitive grammar called Grammatical Framework.

Let this be Story 1:
Things:

    Julius, Skiing, People, Activities

Relationships:

Properties:

    likes (2), in (2)

Facts:

    People like Activities.
    Julius is in People.
    Skiing is in Activities.
    Julius likes Skiing.

and let this be Story 2:
Things:

    I, Skiing, People, Activities

Relationships:

Properties:

    likes (2), in (2)

Facts:

    People like Activities.
    I is in People.
    Skiing is in Activities.
    I likes Skiing.

Consider a world in which Story 1 is true:

there is a person (Julius), an activity (Skiing), a property (liking), and Julius likes Skiing.

Consider a world in which Story 2 is true:

there is a person (I), an activity (Skiing), a property (liking), and I likes Skiing.

In the absence of additional information, Story 1 and Story 2 are the same story, because we can turn Story 1 into Story 2, and vice versa, by turning "Julius" into "I", and vice versa.

This is a simple way to reflect making the propositions of a first-order theory perspectival, though I expect the rules to get more complicated as we add more details to the story. To reflect a theory "from a perspective", a function should exist which associates the terms of one story with the terms of another, preserving the logical meaning of the story. This means that the stories should have equivalent models.
Making a theory perspectival is often a way of replacing constant terms with function terms. For example, if an event occurred at time t, we might say Event(t). All we have to do is choose an element in a set and name it: give time t the name now, instead. We will also provide names for other times. For example, before now is the set of times t such that t < now, and after now is the set of times t such that t > now. The language has now been updated, where times are expressed as functions and relations on the term now.
Thus, it seems initially that "perspective" is not just an arbitrary renaming, but possibly a constraint on the language, where we actually replace a lot of the constant terms with functions and relations defined on a "point of reference" term of some kind.
In fact, mathematically, this is what the visual concept of "perspective" appears to be. Instead of presenting the spatial data of something "purely", perspectival composition in a drawing computes the angle and length of lines as a function of a point of perspective, p. To make perspective clearer, then, instead of relying on natural language words like "I", "before", or "this", we can label an element as a "perspective point", P.
For example, in set theory, we could choose the set {{{},{{{}}}}} as the perspective. In some way, we can define a requirement on the language - not on the model - that other sets be defined in terms of their relationship to {{{},{{{}}}}}. Perhaps we could say it is a "first term", in that one is not allowed to refer to other terms prior to that term. This is similar to the idea of a slice category of a category C, in which the objects are the morphisms into an object of C.

I'm upvoting because of your can-do spirit. But don't reinvent the wheel, my friend. ; ) Linguists over the last 30 years have invented formalisms to do what you're trying to think through aloud here.
